# How to optimize PostgreSQL Configuration? (Is there a tool available?)

Tags: database, optimization, postgresql

In postgresql you have a wealth of optimizations at hand to configure it for your performance needs. The settings for memory usage are still easy enough, but with other options like the cost factors for CPU and IO which are used for the query optimizer are quite a mystery for me. I wonder if there is **a program** available which would do lets say a benchmark of your hardware (CPU speed, memory performance, harddisk speed), analyze your database and come up with the optimal configuration for this specific environment?

EDIT:

Let me clarify this, I know how to tune my database with indexes and the basic memory settings. I also could find out which settings are to be tweaked to get better performance, **but**: I don't have the time, so I want to have a tool which finds this out for me.

Answer (score 3):

Start [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization).

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but the next best thing is the [GUCs: A Three Hour Tour](http://www.pgcon.org/2008/schedule/events/104.en.html) presentation. You can download a [PDF](http://www.pgcon.org/2008/schedule/attachments/44_annotated_gucs_draft1.pdf) from there which gives the recommended values for the settings depending on your system resources.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding indexes is the where most people should start when trying to improve any databases performance.